# Compute 100th derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-fractions

A friend suggested me a rather tricky problem, namely find the $100^{th}$ derivative of 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x^3-x}.
$$
I have computed the zeroth derivative
$$
\frac{x^2+1}{x^3-x}
$$
and the first derivative
$$
\frac{2x(x^3-x)-(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)}{(x^3-x)^2}=\frac{1-x^4-4x^2}{(x^3-x)^2}
$$
but I don't see any obvious structure.

Comment: Two probably won't be enough. Keep on differentiating, and there might be a pattern.

Comment: This may or may not help but $1-x^4 -4x^2 = 2(x^2 -1) -(x^2 +1)^2$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Write your function as
$$
\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^3 - x} = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x}
$$

Answer (score 7):

Hint: since $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ you can easily split $f(x)$ into partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^3-x}=\frac{x^2-1+2}{x^3-x}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x(x-1)(x+1)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x+1}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}+2\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=$$
$$=-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x-1}.$$
Can you end it now?